# Оставить заголовок без изменений при клике на ESC, сохранить новый заголовок при клике на "ENTER" Vue.js (v.2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, state

столкнулся с проблемой...
Дано: У меня есть заголовок, допустим "Карась", при клике на который появляется input с автофокусом, который позволяет редактировать имеющийся заголовок "Карась".

Задача:

1. Если мы отредактировали заголовок, но не хотим его сохранять, при нажатии на 'ESC', должен появляться старый, не отредактированный заголовок.
2. При клике на 'Enter', отредактированный заголовок должен сохраняться.

Я только учусь, моя идея такова. В модели заметки у меня хранится title: 'Карась' и newTitle: '',
но проблема в том, что при использовании v-model и :value у меня изменяется и новый и старый заголовки.

Модель заметки

```
 {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Оладышки',
                newTitle: '',
                descr: 'Это что то на вкусном, но варить я их конечно же не буду!',
                date: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
                priority: 'Medium',
                isEdit: false
            },
```

Поясняю за ниже идущий код.

- функция editNoteTitle(i) переключает флаг isEdit: true/false , в зависимости от флага параграф исчезает и появляется input

Скрытый INPUT/TITLE

```
                        <!---------------------------NOTE TITLE--------------------------->
          <div class="note-title col-10">
            <p id="paragraph"
               class="text-light ml-40px"
               v-if="!notes[i].isEdit"
               @click="editNoteTitle(i)">{{ note.title }}
            </p>

                    <!---------------------------NOTE TITLE CHANGER INPUT--------------------------->
            <b-input v-on:blur="notes[i].isEdit = false"
                     v-model="note.title"
                     :value="note.title"
                     v-if="notes[i].isEdit"
                     @keydown.enter="saveNewTitle(i)"
                     @keydown.esc="loadTitle(i)"
                     autofocus
            />
          </div>
```

ACTIONS/MUTATIONS

```
Actions
        saveNewTitle({commit}, payload) {
            commit('saveNewTitle', payload)
        },
        loadTitle({commit}, payload) {
          commit('loadTitle', payload)
        },
Mutations
        saveNewTitle(state, index) {
            state.notes[index].newTitle = state.notes[index].title
            this.notes[index].isEdit = false
        },
        loadTitle(state, index) {
            state.notes[index].title = this.notes[index].title
        },
```

Не уверен в правильности написания самих мутаций, но это не самая большая проблема. В общем по сути **думаю мой косяк в скрытом инпуте а точнее в бинде значения :value и в v-model**.
Буду благодарен вашим наводкам, отсылкам к что почитать ну и решениям, так как уже 3 дня потратил и защел , как я считаю, в тупик. За ранее благодарю!

Comment: Одновременно v-model и value использовать нет смысла. Вам нужно создавать отдельную промежуточную переменную (массив скорее всего в Вашем случае), инициировать её с нужным заголовком (и в случае изменения самого заголовка в объекте извне через watch подменять в промежуточной переменной) и уже в saveNewTitle сохранять полученное значение.

Comment: Благодарю, в эту сторону не думал! Буду пробовать